# Flink kafka getting serialization issue for timestamp values

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, jackson2

I have a flink Row with TypeInformation of Object class for all columns, I'm getting below error for timestamp columns while serializing Row to kafka. Flink version: 1.14.0

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Java 8 date/time type `java.time.LocalDateTime` not supported by default: add Module "org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310" to enable handling
at org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.valueToTree(ObjectMapper.java:3312)
at org.apache.flink.formats.json.JsonRowSerializationSchema.lambda$createFallbackConverter$8c80cf11$1(JsonRowSerializationSchema.java:266)
... 21 more
```

Comment: The `JsonRowSerializationSchema` is a deprecated class that will be removed in the next future. Why are you using it? Are you using DataStream API? If yes, then why using Row more than defining your own POJO?

Comment: ya, completely agree, can you check my last comment on your PR: github.com/apache/flink-shaded/pull/108, am I on the right path now?